# ECS task cant pull ECR image

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

New to terraform. I have a ECS cluster on a private subnet and the ecs task need to access the ECR image through vpc endpoint only which I have set up. I also have the security group set up.  What am i missing here? Any other endpoints I need to have or need to change my security group? Thanks
It works through if I have a public subnet with nat gateway and igw but I need a private connection through endpoint only.

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = var.access_key
  secret_key = var.secret_key
  region     = "eu-west-2
}
data "aws_region" "current" {}
#vpc
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block           = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_support = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
}
```

```
#private subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.0.0/24"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-2a"
}

#vpc endpoint for ecr
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "ecr_endpoint" {
  vpc_id              = aws_vpc.main.id
  service_name        = "com.amazonaws.${data.aws_region.current.name}.ecr.dkr"
  vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"
  security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.internal_sg.id]
  subnet_ids          = [aws_subnet.private_subnet.id]

}

#Security group
resource "aws_security_group" "internal_sg" {
  name        = "internal-sg"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    description = "Allow inbound HTTP traffic"
  }

}
```

```
# ECS cluster
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "main" {
  name = "ecs-cluster-fargate"
}

# ECS task definition
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task" {
  family                   = "service"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu                      = 512
  memory                   = 2048
  execution_role_arn       = "arn:<>ecsTaskExecutionRole"
  container_definitions    = <<DEFINITION
  [
    {
      "name": "nginx",
      "image": "<ecr-repo>",
      "essential": true,
      "cpu" : 256,
      "memory" : 512,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  DEFINITION
}

# ECS service
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  name            = "service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.main.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.task.arn
  desired_count   = 1
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"

  network_configuration {
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.internal_sg.id]
    subnets          = [aws_subnet.private_subnet.id]
    assign_public_ip = false

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need not just the ECR VPC endpoints, but also the S3 one, as ECR stores image layers in S3. Also make sure the task has all the required IAM permissions to be able to pull from ECR.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html

The link below is more specific information for Fargate tasks, which notes that you need the S3 endpoint when you don't have an Internet Gateway and would like to pull images over the private subnet without having to go out to the public net.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints.html

Lastly, this following detail is often missed so I'll quote it here for visibility:

> The security group attached to the VPC endpoint must allow incoming connections on TCP port 443 from the private subnet of the VPC.